# Downcasting to furthest subclass when calling templated function

Tags: c++, c++17, luabridge

I use LuaBridge to import a large framework of classes into a Lua-accessible framework. LuaBridge uses complex template functions that maintain a list of linkages back to methods and properties of each class. The Lua language itself is loosely typed, and it does not check to see if a method or property exists until you call it. My framework implements a `ClassName` method at every level that allows the Lua programs to know which class it is dealing with.

That's just background for my program. This is a C++ question. I would like to call a function that, in its broadest abstraction, looks something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
do_something_in_lua(T * object); // LuaBridge will create a pointer to a T instance in Lua
```

and call it like this:

```cpp
class foobase
{
public:
    void notify_lua()
    { do_something_in_lua(this); }
};

class foo : public foobase
{
public:
    int some_method();
};

foo x;
x.notify_lua();
```

My question is, is there a simple way for `do_something_in_lua` to use the maximally downcasted version of `T`? Either when I call it or in the templated function? Using `dynamic_cast` is difficult because I would have to maintain an explicit list of every possible subclass to find the right one. Even if it is adding a templated virtual function in `foobase` that returns the desired type of `this`, I would be interested in suggestions for an elegant solution.

I guess a broader version of my question would be, does modern C++ provide any tools for downcasting in template programming (e.g., in `type_traits` or the like) that I should be investigating?

Comment: Or are you asking the opposite? In that case [the C++23 "deducing 'this'" feature](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#Explicit_object_parameter) will help you.

Comment: What I need is the opposite of the base class. The more I think on it, the more I realize it is not going to be possible because templating happens at compile time and this check would have to happen at runtime. So instead, I'm going to have to add something to my base and subclasses to morph them into their respective subtypes. I'm just not sure the best solution.

Comment: In that case you'll have to use good old polymorphism

Comment: Search for double dispatch

Comment: Maybe the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP) is what you want. Othewise, you might simply not provide the member function and always call the free function.

Comment: CRTP is a great suggestion. Unfortunately it won't work in my codebase without massive refactoring, but it's the best answer to the question the way I posed it. If you want to post it, I'll checkmark it.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<void*>(this)` would give you a pointer to the most-derived object. Clause (4) [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to several helpful comments, the solution turns out to be a hybrid of CRTP and Double Dispatch. Here is a version of it based on my example above. I like the fact that it

- requires no pure virtual functions
- does not require templatizing the base class (for reasons specific to my code base)

If I ever need to add a new subclass, I just need to add it to the list in the `std::variant`, and better yet, the compiler will complain until I do so.

```cpp
template <typename T>
void do_something_in_lua(T * object);

// every subclass of foobase must be listed here.
class foosub1;
class foosub2;
using foobase_typed_ptr = std::variant<foosub1*, foosub2*>;

class foobase
{
    foobase_typed_ptr _typedptr;
   
public:
    foobase(const foobase_typed_ptr &ptr) : _typedptr(ptr) {}
    void notify_lua()
    {
        std::visit([](auto const &ptr)
            { do_something_in_lua(ptr); },
            _typedptr);
    }
};

class foosub1 : public foobase
{
public:
    foosub1() : foobase(this) {}
    int some_method1();
};

class foosub2 : public foobase
{
public:
    foosub2() : foobase(this) {}
    int some_method2();
};

// and to call it in code:

foosub2 x;
x.notify_lua(); // now Lua gets called with a foosub2* instead of a foobase*.
```